# Hanon-like violin finger strength exercises

Tags: violin, exercises

I'm looking for a book similar to Hanon for the violin, to develop finger strength, and playing ability for various violin techniques.

Is there anything around designed in such a way that you just warm up with it for your practise and use it to slowly help develop your strength and discipline over time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because requesting off site resources including books is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Like many other musicians, I have learned to despise exercise books. All one learns from exercises are the exercises themselves. The link below is for a set of basic finger exercises for keyboard instruments which can easily be adapted to string instruments. The basic concept behind them is that all fingers are stressed equally and independently, with emphasis on the 4th and 5th fingers. [Basic Finger Exercises for Keyboards.](http://bit.ly/2kxmVXS)